# How to show on the page about the successful addition of an item to the database?

Tags: lightning-aura-components, aura, notification

After adding a record to the database, I am trying to display a success notification, but I am running into an error. What have I done wrong? Here is my code:

**//cmp**

```
<aura:component controller="ContactsManagerAuraController">
...
    <lightning:notificationsLibrary aura:id="notifLib"/>
...
</aura:component>
```

**//js**

```
    createItem : function(component, newItem) {
        let action = component.get("c.saveItems");
        action.setParams({
            "item": newItem
        });
        action.setCallback(this, function(response){
            let state = response.getState();
            if (state === "SUCCESS") {
                let items = component.get("v.items");
                items.push(response.getReturnValue());
                component.set("v.items", items);
                component.set('v.newItem', { 'sobjectType': 'Camping_Item__c',
                                                        'Name': '',
                                                        'Quantity__c': 0,
                                                        'Price__c': 0,
                                                        'Packed__c': false});
                component.find('notifLib').showToast ({ 
                    "title": " Successfully !", 
                    "message": "Entry added successfully." 
                });
            }
        });
        $A.enqueueAction(action);
}
```

[image]

If the section for displaying the notification is removed, then everything works fine. So the matter is that I am wrongly trying to display a notification on the page? How do I fix this?

```
component.find('notifLib').showToast ({ 
                "title": " Successfully !", 
                "message": "Entry added successfully." 
            });
```

Comment: action is undefined, meaning that `component.get("c.saveItems")` is not found in your component markup, you have to fix this and/or handle the exception

Comment: I am a beginner and did not understand your answer. I would like to see an example with a working display of notifications.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the code posted, I see that you did not include the controller attribute in the component.

Something like this,

```
<aura:component controller="MyApexClass">
...
    <lightning:notificationsLibrary aura:id="notifLib"/>
...
</aura:component>
```

If this didn't work, I'd suggest copying the Apex method and paste it in the JS `let action = component.get("c.**paste_here**");`. It needs to be exactly the same because JS is case sensitive.

Comment: Yes sorry forgot to add controller attribute in component in my question (fixed the question). In fact, I had it in the code.

Comment: Previously, my application consisted of several components, but now it is one and my code works well, the notification appears where needed. Thanks for your reply.